# MySQL IN clause displays results in id which is not given in clause

Tags: mysql

Following is my query, in the `in` clause I have not mentioned 34, but the result shows column with bid value 34. bid int type

```
select * from books where  bid in
    ('.6e79b3088c414473','c97f713288ad8005','b8f649e6ee37384d','34a693f48236d9e7',
    'af921be280be6100','a2e6c96c28fc66dc','983d30cec4885bcf','1006c6d3bfae3864',
    '5c0d3a74d58c076c','9f2164de5a9c9acc','a2ae65ca245e1588','279bac514060878f',
    'ecb480d857c11b09','cae2ac89e2c0a805','5bc8906bb41c8c41','842c0aa5203fdf6e',
    '94d6d32e5d0ceca8','9b1d5f8e222bdbc3.')
```

Comment: Can you post the complete string of bid 34 that you mentioned?

Comment: May be the table column value is common among the values present in the in clause

Comment: From where are you getting the `in` values ?

Comment: @Pankit Gami from another table

Comment: can you post the output an this query ?